# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (7:2) File was processed with these loaders:

Tags: reactjs, node.js, матрицы, babel, babel-loader

Кто-то сталкивался с чем-то подобным?

Контекст:
Примерно неделю назад проект на React работал нормально, все было в порядке.

Примерно в тот же период я начал работать над новым проектом, на этот раз используя React Native. Оба проекта находятся на одной и той же рабочей машине, но естественно в разных папках. Во время начальной настройки проекта на React Native пришлось столкнуться с кучей ошибок, и, кажется, в одном из решений этих ошибок я либо обновил пакет (вероятно, необязательно), либо установил новый.

К нестарому проекту я вернулся всего через пару дней и обнаружил эту ошибку. Поэтому я не могу определить, что именно ее вызвало.

Я попробовал npm clean cache + удаление node_modules + удаление package-lock.json, но это не помогло.

Откат к старому коммиту также не решил проблемы (даже на 5 коммитов назад).

Проект изначально был построен с использованием CRA (Create React App).
Файлов типа .babelrc, babel.config.js, webpack.config.js нет.

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/ml-matrix/src/symmetricMatrix.js 7:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (7:2)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| export class SymmetricMatrix extends AbstractMatrix {
|   /** @type {Matrix} */
>   #matrix;
|   get size() {
|     return this.#matrix.size;
```

Пробовал использовать @babel/preset-env, но это не работает.
Удаление node_modules + package-lock.json + npm clean cache - не помогло.
Также пробовал предыдущий коммит, та же ситуация - просто не работает.

Comment: Попробуйте задать вопрос GPT, он с таким быстрее разбреться. И попробуйте обновить NodeJS

Comment: Я уже пробовал такой вариант, но его советы не помогли к сожалению ...

Comment: зайдите на гитхаб библиотеки ml-matrix - https://github.com/mljs/matrix/commits/main, увидите, что последним коммитом "feat: add Symmetric and Distance Matrix" добавился код новых классов, написанный в современном синтаксисе. далее у вас 3 пути: в package.json прописать версию библиотеки, которая не ломает ваше приложение (предыдущая); адаптировать свою разработку к современному синтаксису классов js; подключать matrix.umd.js